# i can't apply curl animation on image

Tags: objective-c

How to apply curl animation on Image.( i want animation like Books page turn from left to right or vice versa. so anyone know about it please help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[oldView removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This thread may be a valuable resource:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/18548-pagecurl-animation-os-3-0-a.html

Comment: ya i know that but curl up does animation form bottom to top and i want left to right curl animation so do you have any idea regarding this. i appreciate your reply it really help me lot. Thank you.

Comment: give me a bit, got to finish up some work, and then i'll try some stuff out, give a holler if I forget

Comment: Can i concate two animation like flip and curl together?